# Git equivalent to bzr-upload

Tags: git

Is there an equivalent to [bzr-upload](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/upload-plugin.html) for git?

It should be able to upload the contents of a tree to a remote location over a dumb protocol (e.g. ftp). Future uploads should only upload the changed files. The history/repo need not be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the directory over, by any means available. The result is a git directory. But it is better to set up a bare repository and work from there (remeber that the git protocol was designed by efficieny freaks worrying about developers over slow links with huge latencies/RTTs). Check out the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book) or one of the excellent tutorials listed [here](http://git-scm.com/documentation).

Comment: No. Git is not installed on the server, and so I can't use the git protocol.

Comment: Then the git repository on the other end won't be of any use (except for backup). Use `rsync` to keep it up to date with your home.

Comment: I specifically said I don't want the repo uploaded. I want the contents of a tree uploaded.

Comment: My cursory reading of `bzr-upload` is that it uploads the repo... OK, you can create an archive of the repository's data under version control by `git archive`, it can create several formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push, rather than pull, I don't think Git supports that functionality without a recipient server on the other side.

However, it would be fairly easy to attach an `rsync` command (or similar) to the [commit hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) in your Git repository, or just run the command manually when you want to upload code. If your `rsync` excludes the `.git` directories in your repo, all of the history stuff won't be uploaded, and only changed files will be touched.